# Phonegap - Assemble with a query result from another query - Sqlite Query

Tags: sqlite, cordova, opendatabase

I can not make a selection via the result of the first

Goal is: 
Do the query on the table "line" pick up your ID and search customers that line the "customer" table

This is my code:

```
    db = window.openDatabase("test", "1.0", "Test DB", 1000000);          
    db.transaction(SelectData,erroSelect,sucessSelect);

    function SelectData(tx)
    {
       tx.executeSql("select id from linha",[],function(tx, response)
       {
            for(i=0; i<response.rows.length; i++)
            {
                tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE line= ?", [response.rows.item(i).id], 
                function (tx, results)
                {
                    for(r=0; r<results.rows.length; r++)
                    {
                        alert(results.rows.item(r).nome); //never worked
                    }   
                }
            }
        },SelectError);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is diffcult to understand from your post, where is the actual error.
Have you tried using **console.log()** call inside each **tx.executeSql()** to ascertain that the function is being executed. 
Alternatively you can use a single query instead of using two **SELECT** statements.

Replace

```
select id from linha
```

with

```
SELECT customers.columnName1, customers.columnName2 
FROM customers INNER JOIN linha ON customers.line = linha.id
```

Comment: I have not used this because I need a structure like this way: 

Title of line  1
customer 1
customer 2 
customer 3 

Title of line 2 
  customer 4 
  customer 5
  customer 6